# SQL Database best extraction

Tags: c#, sql, linq

When extracting data from and SQL database I have always embeded the SQL command into the C# code

```
new SqlCommand(SELECT * from blah blah WHERE blah blah)
```

Recently started using LINQ for other tasks and was wondering what is the best way to get the data I need...

Should I just use SQL to extract all the tables I need, then after that use LINQ to refine the data?

Or something else?

Comment: This answer might get locked for being too subjective (which it is) but before it does: definitely DO NOT do this: _Should I just use sql to extract all the tables I need, then after that use LINQ to refine the data_.  The answer depends on the situation - Is it a commercial project? Is there risk/cost involved associated with learning LINQ? etc

Comment: Indeed, don't cause so much load. Use performant stored procedures and then refine if needed!

Comment: Linq is a great tool but as any programming tool there are cases where it shines and there's are case where it's a nightmare. As a rule of thumb if you database is big, really big, you don't wanna pump it in objects in your app and apply linq to it. If you dat base is not bloated linq+ORM ill work wonders for example

Comment: @markpsmith Sorry slightly confused what's the risk and cost associated with learning linq?  Do you just mean training etc?

Comment: If you tell your boss that the work will take 2 weeks longer because you're learning a new technology, will that extra cost (i.e. paying you) be acceptable?  And IMHO there's risk associated with using a business-critical system as a testing ground for your LINQ experiments (everyone makes mistakes!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what sort of Linq you're using.

If you're using Linq to SQL then that will essentially write your SQL statement for you, but other wise you will need to use a SqlCommand with a hard coded statement or a stored procedure.

Maybe it's time to start looking at using an ORM like Pico, EntityFramework or NHibernate ?